# What is the purpose of IVideoCapture class

Tags: c++, opencv

I am writing a class that will use `cv::VideoCapture` class for various purposes: processing live video stream, processing offline image sequences, processing some other fake data. My version of OpenCV is 3.4. Obviously, the first solution I thought about is to provide the pointer to some `cv::VideoCapture` interface for my class:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(std::shared_ptr<SomeInterfaceToVideoCapture> camera);
}
```

I looked in the OpenCV docs and I actually found out, that indeed in the header `videoio.hpp` there is a forward declaration for `IVideoCapture` (which is the standard naming convention for the interfaces). Even though it seems that `cv::VideoCapture` doesn't actually inherit that `cv::IVideoCapture`, I gave it a try:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(std::shared_ptr<cv::IVideoCapture> camera) {
        if (camera->isOpened()) {
            std::cerr << "VideoCapture device is not working" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
// and later in GTest I create the instance like this:
MyClass myCl(new cv::VideoCapture(0));
```

And I got the error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class cv::IVideoCapture’
             if (camera->isOpened()) {
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videoio.hpp:581:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class cv::IVideoCapture’
 class IVideoCapture;
```

So, obviously this `cv::IVideoCapture` interface is never defined. However, in the same header in the class `cv::VideoCapture` there are two protected fields:

```
protected:
    Ptr<CvCapture> cap;
    Ptr<IVideoCapture> icap;
```

I couldn't find any documentation on how this `icap` field can be used. Of course, technically I can inherit `cv::VideoCapture` and then have access to `icap` but I don't see the purpose.

Since in the class `cv::VideoCapture` all methods are virtual, I can still override the default behavior for testing, simulation, or whatever applications, which is good. But, just out of curiosity: **my question is: what is the purpose of the forward declaration of `cv::IVideoCapture` and what is the purpose of the protected field `icap`. What kind of pattern is that?**

Comment: [may be of use](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp) it is used a lot in here

Comment: Thanks @GPPK. It looks like PImpl idiom (almost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `IVideoCapture` class is used inside the `VideoCapture` as a [pimpl idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl), and at the same time is the actual interface. Classes like `VideoCapture_IntelPerC` implement it and are used inside `VideoCapture` The difference is that is was declared public, but of course I cannot find any reason for OpenCV user to actually use this `IVideoCapture` interface.